# nginx: aliasing or rooting an autoindex directory automatically append an index.html to the path

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx config:

```
location ~ ^/system/filedir/scripts {
  autoindex on;
}

location ~ ^/filedir/scripts {
  alias /system/filedir/scripts/;
}
```

When I visit `http://myserver.com/system/filedir/scripts`everything works fine and I can see the list of files contained by the scripts directory.

But when I visit `http://myserver.com/filedir/scripts` I have the following error:

```
[error] 2083#0: *83335 "/system/filedir/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), request: "GET /filedir/scripts/ HTTP/1.1"
```

I cannot get rid of the index.html addition and get the file listing.
The same is happening if I try

```
 location ~ ^/filedir/scripts {
    root /system/;
 }
```

Here's my nginx.conf:

```
# daemon off;
# user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
# error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
# error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                     '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                     '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_min_length 500;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_types  text/plain
                text/html
                text/xml
                text/css
                text/comma-separated-values
                text/javascript application/x-javascript
                application/atom+xml
                application/json
                application/xml
                application/rss+xml
                image/svg+xml
                application/vnd.ms-fontobject
                application/x-font-ttf;

    include my_sites/*;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a rewrite:

```
server {
  location ~ ^/system/filedir/scripts/ {
    autoindex on;
  }

  location ~ ^/filedir/scripts/ {
    rewrite ^/filedir/scripts/(.*)$ /system/filedir/scripts/$1 last;
  }
```

Or a proxy_pass:

```
server {
  resolver 8.8.8.8;

  location ~ ^/system/filedir/scripts/ {
    autoindex on;
  }

  location ~ ^/filedir/scripts/ {
    proxy_pass http://$host/system/$uri;
  }
```

I've tried combinations with alias, root, but they all failed.